# Entity Framework Code First mapping composite key in join table where foreign keys are not exposed in model

Tags: .net, entity-framework, many-to-many, ef-code-first

I have a join table with an additional field relevant to the join:

```
VirtualDatastreamId  INT  NOT NULL
DatastreamId         INT  NOT NULL
FormulaElement       INT  NOT NULL
```

All columns are the primary key.

The POCO this is mapped to is:

```
public class VirtualDatastreamMap 
{
    public virtual Datastream Datastream { get; set; }
    public virtual VirtualDatastream VirtualDatastream { get; set; }
    public virtual string FormulaElement { get; set; }
}
```

I do not have foreign key properties in the model as, to me, the concept of a foreign key is an implementation detail and should be encapsulated by the relationships specified by the class. I'd prefer not to add these if possible.

How do I map this with Fluent API? I was hoping for something like the below (which unfortunately doesn't work):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VirtualDatastreamMap>()
            .HasKey(vdm => 
                new 
                { 
                    DatastreamId = vdm.Datastream.Id, 
                    VirtualDatastreamId = vdm.VirtualDatastream.Id, 
                    FormulaElement = vdm.FormulaElement 
                });
```

The field names of the anonymous type have to be named as an object cannot have two fields with the same name.

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733254/how-do-i-map-a-composite-primary-key-in-entity-framework-4-code-first) that this issue was raised in the answer but there doesn't seem to be anything further.

If it's not possible, which is a better option?

1. Add the foreign key properties to the model
2. Add an `Id` field to the database and the model

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column of the composite primary key has to be mapped to a scalar property in the entity. Your ideal solution will not work.

In Option 2 you would have to create a unique key also and check for unique key violations. EF does not have built in support for unique keys. Hence I would pick option 1.

Comment: Happy with that. I have created the foreign key properties. It's not ideal but it works.